# Dispaly Quantity in POS(Point of Sale) in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, point-of-sale, odoo-9

Current I am working on Point Of Sale(POS) module in Odoo8,I wanted to know how to display the quantity of products in a POS session(if you observe the image, In right top Corner its Showing the price, Like that I need to display the available quantity at top left corner).[a session in POS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e2la.png) 
Thank you.

Comment: This is a user requirement dear !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This not available in ODOO 8 and 9, So create your custom code dear !!!!!

Comment: You need to do custom development to achieve this !!! .

Comment: Thank you guys ...yes I want to make a custom POS interface. is there any idea how to customize the interface ....